# Unable to upload images using the Media Library

Tags: uploads, media-library, 500-internal-error

I have had a site that has been working perfectly for the past few months. Then all of a sudden when I go to upload an image via the Media Manager on the Admin Dashboard I get a 500: Internal Server Error.

I don't understand what might be causing this. I checked my server error logs and there is nothing in their that relates to this error. I noticed that I can upload small files but just not large ones and by large I'm only talking between (3 - 5 Mb).

I've tried a few different things but they have not worked.

- Deactivated my theme - no change
- Deactivated my plugins - no change
- made change to `htaccess` file - no change

I added this to my `htaccess` as I read it could be a security issue, but it did not work.

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
<Files async-upload.php>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</Files>
</IfModule>
```

I also added this to my `wp-config` file:

`DEFINE('WP_MEMORY', '64M')` but that made no difference either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this happen on a vanilla WordPress install on the same server?  I saw you said you disabled your theme and plugins, but some make changes and don't undo them on deactivation.

Answer (score 0):

1. after change your memory limit , open your web page in some other browser or delete all your history and cache values in your browsr,,,,

Comment: That didn't work

Comment: Change your Memory limit as :  define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '296M'); , and check after delete your past browser history,,,

Comment: Unfortunately, that also did not work

Comment: Please read this [how to answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I think php version is issue , Add following code to .htaccess and then try to upload :

```
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php
```